# Open Template Path hint in magento2

Tags: magento-2.1.3

I want to enable template path hint in Magento 2 by code as we do in Magento 1.9 we set params so how we can do in Magento 2?

Comment: For particular url?

Comment: yup i think moduel-developer we can do

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to enable 'Hints', using the method from the "Developer" module. From here, you can create a plugin for the frontend:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngineFactory">
    <plugin name="debug_hints" type="Magento\Developer\Model\TemplateEngine\Plugin\DebugHints" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

of the type:

```
    /**
     * Wrap template engine instance with the debugging hints decorator, depending of the store configuration
     *
     * @param TemplateEngineFactory $subject
     * @param TemplateEngineInterface $invocationResult
     *
     * @return TemplateEngineInterface
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterCreate(
        TemplateEngineFactory $subject,
        TemplateEngineInterface $invocationResult
    ) {
        $storeCode = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
        if ($this->scopeConfig->getValue($this->debugHintsPath, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeCode)
            && $this->devHelper->isDevAllowed()) {
            $showBlockHints = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                self::XML_PATH_DEBUG_TEMPLATE_HINTS_BLOCKS,
                ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                $storeCode
            );
            return $this->debugHintsFactory->create([
                'subject' => $invocationResult,
                'showBlockHints' => $showBlockHints,
            ]);
        }
        return $invocationResult;
    }
```

It will replace the template engine with its own class `Magento\Developer\Model\TemplateEngine\Decorator\DebugHints`(providing 'Hints' are disabled and verification passed).

In this class, 'Hints' are implemented in the following methods:

```
    /**
     * Insert debugging hints into the rendered block contents
     *
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockInterface $block, $templateFile, array $dictionary = [])
    {
        $result = $this->_subject->render($block, $templateFile, $dictionary);
        if ($this->_showBlockHints) {
            $result = $this->_renderBlockHints($result, $block);
        }
        $result = $this->_renderTemplateHints($result, $templateFile);
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Insert template debugging hints into the rendered block contents
     *
     * @param string $blockHtml
     * @param string $templateFile
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _renderTemplateHints($blockHtml, $templateFile)
    {
        return <<<HTML
<div class="debugging-hints" style="position: relative; border: 1px dotted red; margin: 6px 2px; padding: 18px 2px 2px 2px;">
<div class="debugging-hint-template-file" style="position: absolute; top: 0; padding: 2px 5px; font: normal 11px Arial; background: red; left: 0; color: white; white-space: nowrap;" onmouseover="this.style.zIndex = 999;" onmouseout="this.style.zIndex = 'auto';" title="{$templateFile}">{$templateFile}</div>
{$blockHtml}
</div>
HTML;
    }

    /**
     * Insert block debugging hints into the rendered block contents
     *
     * @param string $blockHtml
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockInterface $block
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _renderBlockHints($blockHtml, \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockInterface $block)
    {
        $blockClass = get_class($block);
        return <<<HTML
<div class="debugging-hint-block-class" style="position: absolute; top: 0; padding: 2px 5px; font: normal 11px Arial; background: red; right: 0; color: blue; white-space: nowrap;" onmouseover="this.style.zIndex = 999;" onmouseout="this.style.zIndex = 'auto';" title="{$blockClass}">{$blockClass}</div>
{$blockHtml}
HTML;
    }
```

Summing up, to enable 'Hints', you need to add your own plugin (without conditions verification) and replace the template engine this way:

```
In the file: vendor/module/etc/frontend.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngineFactory">
        <plugin name="debug_hints_own" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\DebugHints" sortOrder="9"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Next, create a class: `Vendor\Module\Plugin\DebugHints`:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Developer\Model\TemplateEngine\Decorator\DebugHintsFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngineFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngineInterface;

class DebugHints
{
    /**
     * @var DebugHintsFactory
     */
    protected $debugHintsFactory;

    /**
     * @param DebugHintsFactory $debugHintsFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        DebugHintsFactory $debugHintsFactory
    ) {
        $this->debugHintsFactory = $debugHintsFactory;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param TemplateEngineFactory $subject
     * @param TemplateEngineInterface $invocationResult
     *
     * @return TemplateEngineInterface
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterCreate(
        TemplateEngineFactory $subject,
        TemplateEngineInterface $invocationResult
    ) {
        return $this->debugHintsFactory->create([
            'subject' => $invocationResult,
            'showBlockHints' => 1,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And finally, refresh cache, run compilation - and that should make it work. You can also add your own verification (if needed).

Answer (score 2):

From Backend You can easily do it by below settings:

> Store > Configuration > Advanced > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints
>   for Storefront > Yes

Comment: I assume he is not asking that. This will enable path hints for the whole frontend.